# What happens when you pass an expression to a function which has passing by value-result?

Tags: function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm attending a course of principles of programming languages and there's this exercise where I'm supposed to tell what gets printed by this program:

```
{

int x=2;

void A (val/res int y) 
{
    x++; 
    write(y); 
    y=y+2; 
}

A(x)
A(x+1)
write (x); 

}
```

A is a function with value/result parameters passing, so right before returning it should copy the final value of its formal parameter (y) in the actual parameter. When A first gets called its actual parameter is x, so there's no problem there. However, the second call to A has x+1 as the actual parameter.
What does that mean? Maybe the final value of y gets lost because there's no variable where to copy it? Or maybe I should consider it like an equation, so if the final value of y is 7 I get that x + 1 = 7, and then the value of x is 6?

Comment: Not sure what language this is, but I would think `x+1` creates a new variable, similar to: `int z = x + 1; A(z);`.

Comment: I don't think it is any specific language, probably just generic pseudo-code. I'm not sure that that's the right answer though, because we never did anything like that in class.

Answer (score 1):

It means the *value* of the argument is copied to `y`:

- When `x`=2, `A(x)` copies 2 to `y` at the start of `A`
- When `x`=4, `A(x+1)` copies the *value* of `x+1`, or 5, to `y` at the start of `A`

However, as you pointed, out, passing `x+1` for a value/result parameter is problematic, and I would expect any language supporting this type of parameter would not consider it legal, for just the reason you cite.  If it is considered legal, how it is accomplished would be up to the language definition; I do not believe there is a standard way to handle this.

Comment: So, since there's no detail regarding this on the description of the exercise, this might very well be a trick question. Before posting here I tried to search for infos about the value/result parameters passing, but this the only vaguely useful source I was able to retrieve: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/general/parameters.html

"copy going out of the procedure, the formal parameters are copied back into the actual parameters. (Note that this only makes sense if the actual parameter is a variable, or has a l-value, such as an array element.)"